# UITableView does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Type ‘TVViewController’ does not conform to protocol ‘UITableViewDataSource’

I'm fairly new to programming and the error is very vague so I don't know where to begin troubleshooting.

```
class WeeksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    //Categories
    var categories = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]

    //Number of sections
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    //Defining the headers
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    //Number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //Cell as identifier & category as the class
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You copied and pasted Swift 2 code. These are the proper Swift 3+ methods

```
class WeeksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    //Categories
    var categories = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]

    //Number of sections
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
        return categories.count
    }

    //Defining the headers
    func func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categories[section]
    }

    //Number of rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //Cell as identifier & category as the class
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryRow
        return cell
    }

}
```

It's always worth it to have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a misspelling in the name of the `numberOfRows` data source method and the `cellForRow` signature is also a bit off.

Instead of these:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}
...
func func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // 
}
```

You probably want these:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return categories.count
}
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // code
}
```